# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException Java

Tags: java, java-io, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am Create a Program which is download file from server

```
public void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir, String user, String pass, String FileName)
            throws IOException {
        String authString = user + ":" + pass;

        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();

            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }

            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
```

so when i am download file using parameters i faced a error 
the output is

```
Content-Type = application/http
Content-Disposition = null
Content-Length = 3217551
fileName = 13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Cam\13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav
 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at dynakode.utility.Downloader.downloadFile(Downloader.java:65)
    at dynakode.camera.DynakodeCamera.cennection(DynakodeCamera.java:50)
    at dynakode.camera.DynakodeCamera.main(DynakodeCamera.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

as u can see Error is The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect so how can i fix this

I am Change this line

```
  String saveFilePath = saveDir + "\\" + "test.dav";
```

i am giving name manually than file is download to driver

the output is

```
Content-Type = application/http
Content-Disposition = null
Content-Length = 3217551
fileName = 13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav

File downloaded
```

which is i want

**issue Fixed**

@TAsk you are write there is issue of Space but at C:/cam .. the is at file name which comes from server there is space `" 13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav"` which is create problem 
so i am trim all path

```
 saveFilePath = saveFilePath.trim();
```

using this an d issue fixed

Comment: what exception says to you?

Comment: exception show in post you can see it

Comment: I can see it. I mean does file exists at desired location as mentioned in the exception `C:\Cam\13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav`

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to pinpoint the exact line of code which is throwing the error?

Comment: yeh when i am set manual name then it will works

Comment: the error is ON     // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

Comment: 1.Does the file You download exist on Your drive (was it really downloaded?)
2.Can You try to force the filename as a first step to find the reason? like fileName="test"

Comment: file is exist and when i am change file name like any kind of string than its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your String has `\13` in path which is considering it as a character representation.

```
C:\Cam\13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav
      ^
```

You should change it to either `/` or `\\`

So change your `saveFilePath`

```
String saveFilePath = saveDir + "\\" + fileName;
String saveFilePath = saveDir + "/" + fileName;
```

### But

This should not be the case here because of `File.separator()` (Pointed out by  `user2864740`) so one more reason according to me can cause this problem which I believe is extra space before `C:` or somewhere in path.

```
" C:\Cam"+File.separator+"13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav"
 ^//<-------Extra Space you can use string.trim() to remove extra spaces
```

**EDIT**

Than the last thing which I think is directory (`Cam`) is not present that could be the last option which can cause this.

Comment: ohky how can i fix this

Comment: I am getting same error

Comment: I do not believe this is the problem. The error message gives the *actual* file name (so escapes in string literals need not apply) and the OP is using `String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;`.

Comment: Same Error Not working

Comment: You have o check .. my edited post .. space is not a issue

Comment: @TAsk you are write there is issue of Space but at C:/cam .. the is at file name which comes from server there is space `" 13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav"` which is create problem 
so i am trim all path 

    saveFilePath = saveFilePath.trim();

using this an d issue fixed

Comment: @Ashish Oh Finally!! 0_0 But I can's see any space in Exception.

Comment: But in output after equals at fileName = 13.25.00-13.26.00[R][0@0][0].dav have a space bt at code i don't give any space and you can vate my post for my increase my reputation

Answer (score 0):

Because the path you specified is not the same as the path is it expecting so it is throwing the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Make sure you have created the `cam` directory under the `c` drive

Comment: yes I created it already.. the file is download when i will give a manual name like number text any thing

Comment: these are some basic Exception so instead of posting it over here a simple debugging or google search will do the job

Comment: This is an output file. It isn't 'expecting' anything.

Comment: @EJP It is expecting the "the `cam` directory under the `c` drive". (Although the wording in the first sentence could be cleaned up.)

Comment: @EJP Ok in that case the output file must have some harry potter's wand to make the directory specified in the path because the OP never specified the code to make a directory if it doesnot exist